# Run elastic beanstalk .ebextensions config for specific environments

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I have the following config

```
0_logdna.config
commands:
  01_install_logdna:
    command: "/home/ec2-user/logdna.sh"
  02_restart_logdna:
    command: "service logdna-agent restart"

files:
  "/home/ec2-user/logdna.sh" :
    mode: "000777"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/sh
      RACK_ENV=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k RACK_ENV)
      echo "$RACK_ENV"
      if [ $RACK_ENV == production ]
      then
        rpm --import https://repo.logdna.com/logdna.gpg
        echo "[logdna]
        name=LogDNA packages
        baseurl=https://repo.logdna.com/el6/
        enabled=1
        gpgcheck=1
        gpgkey=https://repo.logdna.com/logdna.gpg" | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/logdna.repo
        LOGDNA_INGESTION_KEY=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k LOGDNA_INGESTION_KEY)
        yum -y install logdna-agent
        logdna-agent -k $LOGDNA_INGESTION_KEY # this is your unique Ingestion Key
        # /var/log is monitored/added by default (recursively), optionally add more dirs here
        logdna-agent -d /var/app/current/log/logstasher.log
        logdna-agent -d /var/app/containerfiles/logs/sidekiq.log
        # logdna-agent --hostname allows you to pass your AWS env metadata to LogDNA (remove # to uncomment the line below)
        # logdna-agent --hostname `{"Ref": "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }`
        # logdna -t option allows you to tag the host with tags (remove # to uncomment the line below)
        #logdna-agent -t `{"Ref": "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }`
        chkconfig logdna-agent on
        service logdna-agent start
      fi
```

I want to be able to only run this config for my production environment but each time i run this code, i get an error that says

```
ERROR   [Instance: i-091794aa00f84ab36,i-05b6d0824e7a0f5da] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...not found
/home/ec2-user/logdna.sh: line 17: logdna-agent: command not found
/home/ec2-user/logdna.sh: line 18: logdna-agent: command not found
error reading information on service logdna-agent: No such file or directory
logdna-agent: unrecognized service.
```

Not sure why this is not working. When i echo RACK_ENV i get `production` as the value so i know that is correct but why is it failing my if statement and why is it not working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `echo` will lead to malformed `/etc/yum.repos.d/logdna.repo`. To set it up properly, please use the following (**indentations** for `EOL2` are important):

```
files:
  "/home/ec2-user/logdna.sh" :
    mode: "000777"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/sh
      RACK_ENV=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k RACK_ENV)
      echo "$RACK_ENV"
      if [ $RACK_ENV == production ]
      then
        rpm --import https://repo.logdna.com/logdna.gpg
        cat >/etc/yum.repos.d/logdna.repo << 'EOL2'
      [logdna]
      name=LogDNA packages
      baseurl=https://repo.logdna.com/el6/
      enabled=1
      gpgcheck=1
      gpgkey=https://repo.logdna.com/logdna.gpg
      EOL2
        LOGDNA_INGESTION_KEY=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k LOGDNA_INGESTION_KEY)
        yum -y install logdna-agent
        logdna-agent -k $LOGDNA_INGESTION_KEY # this is your unique Ingestion Key
        # /var/log is monitored/added by default (recursively), optionally add more dirs here
        logdna-agent -d /var/app/current/log/logstasher.log
        logdna-agent -d /var/app/containerfiles/logs/sidekiq.log
        # logdna-agent --hostname allows you to pass your AWS env metadata to LogDNA (remove # to uncomment the line below)
        # logdna-agent --hostname `{"Ref": "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }`
        # logdna -t option allows you to tag the host with tags (remove # to uncomment the line below)
        #logdna-agent -t `{"Ref": "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }`
        chkconfig logdna-agent on
        service logdna-agent start
      fi
```

For further troubleshooting please check `/var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log` file.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So currently if i run your answer, it works fine given that i am deploying to my production environment. But i want to also deploy this to e.g my staging environment but I dont want to install logdna, how do i execute that? Basically can i also add an if condition in my commands section?

Comment: @KingsleySimon Hi. My answer addresses the original error and issue posted. For the staging issue, maybe you can use [test](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands) in your `commands` so that they run only when test succeeds. You can try, and if have errors, new question could be made.